# Taggit Django - Return View of Posts Based on User Post Tags)

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I have recently been playing around Taggit. I have managed to filter my Posts model, based on different Tags by adding the following filter `.filter(tags__name__in='categoryone')`.

Although, would anyone be able to provide me with guidance on how to filter my Posts based on the tags my user has already used within his or her previous posts?

So for example, if my user has previously created a Post within the "categoryone" tag, all the posts he or she would see on their Post Feed would be tags relevant to "categoryone" but he or she wouldn't see any posts within "categorytwo" or "categorythree" unless he or she makes a post within either or both of those categories.

I was hoping something such as `.filter(tags=self.request.user)` would work, but this is throwing a Tag Instance error. Ideally I'm wanting to add a filter which filters through the existing tags my user has used within their previous posts.

Any examples would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Thanks!

--

Views.py (Query for PostListView)

```
  def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        tags = Tag.objects.filter(post__author=user)

        qs = Follow.objects.filter(user=user)
        qa = Tag.objects.filter(post__author=user)
        follows = [user]
        tags = [user]
        for obj in qs:
            follows.append(obj.follow_user)
        for obj in qa:
            obj.user = self.request.user
        return Post.objects.filter(author__in=follows).filter(author__in=tags).order_by('-date_posted')
```

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='srv_media')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

Comment: get the user tags first and then use them for filtering posts

Comment: @Kurohige Thank you for your response! I have updated my original post on here with my Views.py queryset - Am I on the right track? I'm stuck with this error currently `'Tag' object has no attribute 'post_author'` Within my Posts model, I have a foreignkey assigned which I reference as "author".

Comment: To get an exhaustive answer you should give an exhaustive question :) please add the interesting models class also. Thanks

Comment: @Kurohige Ah I'll add them now Kurohige! :-) Sorry, I'm still a little new to Django, so I do apologise if any of my code looks a little sloppy, i'm just trying to learn bit by bit! :-) But yes, I'll add the Models now!

Comment: @Kurohige I've updated my original question and have provided the Post model. I've also managed to get rid of the Tag Instance error I was receiving (My Post Feed is displaying again now) but I'm only seeing my own posts, rather than the posts of both mine and my users. (I think I've accidentally filtered the posts to show under the current user who's logged in, rather than filtering the tags) - I've also updated my Views.py code within my original question above since I was able to get rid of the Tag Instance error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to give an answer based on your current work:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        tags = Tag.objects.filter(post__author=user)

        qs = Follow.objects.filter(user=user)
        qa = Tag.objects.filter(post__author=user)
        follows = [user]
        tags = [user] 
        for obj in qs:
            follows.append(obj.follow_user)
        for obj in qa:
            tags.append(obj.post.author)
        return Post.objects.filter(author__in=follows).filter(author__in=tags).order_by('-date_posted')
```

Comment: Ahhh you did it!! You absolute star! Thank you so so much! :-) I've marked your answer as correct. I wasn't too far off, but I certainly wouldn't of been able to figure out the last bit without your guidance! If I can make any donations for your time, please let me know!! :-) Thank you!!

Comment: @Jarjar95 :) glad to help